# plotting factors to multiple rows with facet_nested_wrap GGPLOT

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, facet, facet-wrap

I would like to ask for your help regarding a `facet_nested_wrap` argument.

Let me first describe my data.

I am using the TRACE bribery risk matrix and its 4 domains and 9 subdomains.

- Domains: "Opportunity", "Deterrence", "Transparency", "Oversight".
- Subdomains: "Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage", "Dissuasion", "Enforcement", "Processes", "Interests", "Free press", "Civil society".

"Opportunity" has 3 subdomains: "Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage".

"Deterrence" has 2 subdomains: "Dissuasion", "Enforcement".

"Transparency" has 2 subdomains: "Processes", "Interests".

"Oversight" has 2 subdomains: "Free press", "Civil society".

Function `facet_nested_wrap` can be found in package `ggh4x`, that can be installed from GitHub with

```
devtools::install_github('teunbrand/ggh4x')
```

I made the following graph:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggh4x)

df <- data.frame(

scope = c("GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG",
"ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP"),

value = c(18.69760, 25.15200, 30.54616, 34.35660, 28.47889, 18.44293,   
16.99592, 19.10984, 22.32335, 20.00916, 28.66086, 30.22386, 37.56469, 31.69484, 20.42255, 18.80105, 23.36370, 25.05658),

domain = c("Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Deterrence",
"Deterrence", "Transparency", "Transparency", "Oversight", "Oversight", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Deterrence", "Deterrence", "Transparency", "Transparency", "Oversight", "Oversight"),

subdomain = c("Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage", "Dissuasion", "Enforcement", "Processes", "Interests", "Free press", "Civil society", "Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage", "Dissuasion", "Enforcement", "Processes", "Interests", "Free press", "Civil society")
) 

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= as.numeric(value), y= reorder(domain, -value), fill = scope)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "black", width= 0.6, 
           position = position_dodge(width= 0.8)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)), vjust=-0.5, color="black", 
            size=3.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) + 
  labs(title = "Weighted risk scores per portfolio",
       x = "",
       y = "", 
       fill = NULL) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16)) + 
  facet_nested_wrap(vars(domain, subdomain), scales = "free") + 
  expand_limits(x=c(0, 50))
```

When plotting, I would like to have the facets divided by 4 rows for the 4 domains. Now I have only 3, and the domains are "cut" in half in a way (the domain "Oversight" is in the first row, together with "Opportunity").

I would like to plot the first domain "Opportunity" as the first row, the second domain "Oversight" in the second row, and so on. The problem is that "Opportunity" has 3 subdomains, while the rest only 2.

I looked into the bleed argument, but could not make is work :(
https://rdrr.io/github/teunbrand/ggh4x/man/facet_nested_wrap.html

Can somebody please help me?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `facet_nested_wrap()` function primarily restructures strips, meaning that if you can't get the layout correctly in `facet_wrap()` it won't be correct in `facet_nested_wrap()`. This is also in the detail section of the documentation that reads: 'This function only merges strips in the same row or column as they appear through regular `facet_wrap()` layout behaviour'. That said, one remedy could be to fill the 3rd panel of 2-panel domains with a dummy variable with `geom_blank()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggh4x)

df <- data.frame(
  
  scope = c("GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG","GPFG",
            "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP", "ABP"),
  
  value = c(18.69760, 25.15200, 30.54616, 34.35660, 28.47889, 18.44293,   
            16.99592, 19.10984, 22.32335, 20.00916, 28.66086, 30.22386, 37.56469, 31.69484, 20.42255, 18.80105, 23.36370, 25.05658),
  
  domain = c("Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Deterrence",
             "Deterrence", "Transparency", "Transparency", "Oversight", "Oversight", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Opportunity", "Deterrence", "Deterrence", "Transparency", "Transparency", "Oversight", "Oversight"),
  
  subdomain = c("Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage", "Dissuasion", "Enforcement", "Processes", "Interests", "Free press", "Civil society", "Interaction", "Expectation", "Leverage", "Dissuasion", "Enforcement", "Processes", "Interests", "Free press", "Civil society")
) 

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= as.numeric(value), y= reorder(domain, -value), fill = scope)) + 
  geom_col(colour = "black", width= 0.6, 
           position = position_dodge(width= 0.8)) + 
  geom_blank(
    data = data.frame(
      domain = c("Deterrence", "Oversight", "Transparency"), 
      subdomain = "z"
    ),
    inherit.aes = FALSE
  ) +
  theme_bw() + 
  coord_flip() + 
  geom_text(aes(label = round(value, 1)), vjust=-0.5, color="black", 
            size=3.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) + 
  labs(title = "Weighted risk scores per portfolio",
       x = "",
       y = "", 
       fill = NULL) + 
  theme(legend.position = "bottom",
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size = 22),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_text(size = 14),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 16)) + 
  facet_nested_wrap(vars(domain, subdomain), scales = "free",
                    ncol = 3) + 
  expand_limits(x=c(0, 50))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

As a side note: the 'bleed' argument is about the strips and how they get merged, but perhaps the documentation could be clearer on this.